# In an element of a matrix, can I refer in an element to its own row or column?

Tags: matrix

In an expression inside the matrix, can I obtain the indices of the element where this expression is located? Also, can I refer to other elements of that same matrix, like in spreadsheets?

Comment: The standard command is [Position](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Position.html) which gives the index/position where the expression or the pattern is located in the matrix.  I do not understand the other part of your question.

Comment: "can I refer to other elements of that same matrix, like in spreadsheets?" - no, matrices in *Mathematica* do not work that way. What did you need a recursive reference for?

Comment: @J.M. I guess it is a typical case of XY problem, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem

Comment: You can refer to other elements of that same matrix by manipulating the position you get, then accessing the manipulated position. For example, if it's just one element that matches a pattern `patt` (which can just be an expression you want to match),`First @ Position[array, patt] + {1, 0}` would give the position of the next element along the first dimension. Then you could use `Extract` or `Part` to get the element at that new position (`Extract` being a little more convenient). Without more details it's a bit hard to tell what would help, though; I'd recommend editing your question! :)

Comment: Without seeing your actual use case, I don’t know if this is relevant, but you might look into MapIndexed.